# What's the ideal way to store dropdown list text/values in a Postgres 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, web-applications, dropdownbox

What's the optimal way to store values for a select list in a web-app with Postgres?

If I use an enum, this has the benefit of acting as a constraint for whatever column is set to that type (only allowing possible values). I can also write rather normal queries to pull those values to populate the select... but this has the drawback of requiring the option text and value to be identical.

If I create a table to store these, I can have columns for both value and text, and perhaps even a third (comment/description, whatever). However, it means a full table for every set of values, of which I expect several dozen throughout the webapp. Not sure why this feels like a "heavier" solution than enums, but it does. (A "create enum" statement plus possible "alter enum" in the future vs. a "create table" plus many initial insert statements and maybe more in the future.)

Nor can I create a single table for all dropdown lists, because then I would need to do convoluted constraint logic in the various tables that related to that.

Is there a code pattern that is ideal for this problem that I'm unaware of?

The solution doesn't need to be portable to other database engines... I'm more than happy to use a postgres-only solution.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "use an enum." Do you mean you'd create a separate enum column for each menu, with all the possible menu selections defined in the enum list? Can you provide an example schema?

Comment: Don't use enums, use one table for each lookup - it is definitely not a "heavy" solution. Databases were made to manage tables - there is nothing wrong with creating many of them. The "single table for all dropdowns" is an anti-pattern known as "one true lookup-table". It doesn't buy you anything but has several disadvantages (not being able to use proper foreign keys is one of them)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Databases were made to manage large tables. But my brain wasn't made to manage databases. I wasn't aware that the one-table thing was a named anti-pattern, but it did look like it was a bad idea. Not sure why you couldn't use foreign keys though.

Comment: Well you _can_ use foreign keys, they are just nonsense. They would not prevent assigning a (lookup) value for an "Order Status" to a "Customer Address Type" - which defeats the whole purpose of a foreign key

Comment: Putting all menus in one table is *not* OTLT. You're not looking up a cross-referenced value from a conglomerated set of unrelated tables, you're simply  fetching records. Suggesting you create a separate table for each menu's selections is like suggesting you create a separate table for each customer's orders. You'd never be able to query "which menu has selection HELP" because you'd have no idea what tables(s) to look at. Adding a new menu should be doable just by INSERT, it shouldn't require schema modifications.

Comment: _Nor can I create a single table for all dropdown lists, because then I would need to do convoluted constraint logic in the various tables that related to that._ How so? Can you expand on this? It should never be more complicated than a single WHERE clause or a single-field JOIN.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: "menus" and "dropdowns" are two different things (at least to me). I agree with you that menu texts (labels, localization of the UI) should go into a single table (_if_ stored in the database). Dropdowns are usually used to select a value for a single column (e.g. "order status", "address type"). I was talking about _those_ regarding the OTLT, not about menus or localizing frontend labels.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Heh yeah, OK, I see how you're interpreting it. It's... not explained very thoroughly, I went totally in the other direction with it. :)

Comment: I confirm that this isn't for menus, but for select lists. Few if any of these would overlap in allowed values.

Comment: OK gotcha, re-reading the question again, and I have no idea how I got that idea, heh.